# How to find the greatest number of times each element occurs in a nested array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to find the greatest number of times each element occurs in a nested array?

I am looking to find the greatest number of times each element occurs in any of the subarrays.  I am NOT looking for the element that occurs the most times in the entire nested array.

Let's say my nested array is [[2, 3, 5], [3, 3, 5], [2, 2, 3, 5]].

The number 2 appears two times in one of the subarrays.  The number 3 appears two times in one of the subarrays.  The number 5 appears one time in one of the subarrays.

The end result I am looking for is [2, 2, 3, 3, 5].

What is the best way to do this? Below is my approach, which is not very good.

```
function makeNewArray(arr) {

    // add the # to the numbers that appear once and add the ## to the numbers that appear twice
    for (var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
        for (var i = 0; i < arr[j].length; i++) {
          if (arr[j][i] === arr[j][i+1]) {
            arr[j][i] = arr[j][i] + '#';
            arr[j][i+1] = arr[j][i+1] + '#';    
          } else {
            arr[j][i] = arr[j][i] + '#';
          }     
      }
    }   

    // flatten the array
    arr = arr.reduce(function(a, b) { return a.concat(b); });

    // remove the duplicates from the array
    arr = arr.filter(function(a, b) { return arr.indexOf(a) == b; });

    // remove the ## and # from the array 
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = parseInt(arr[i]);
    }

    return arr;
}

makeNewArray([[2, 3, 5], [3, 3, 5], [2, 2, 3, 5]]);
```

Comment: How do you get [2,3,5,3,2]?

Answer (score 0):

Just based on your question and not the result you expect that I don't really get, here is a working solution that will find the highest number of occurrence.

```js
var a = [
  [2, 3, 5],
  [3, 3, 5],
  [2, 2, 3, 5]
];
var o = {};
var max = 0;
var highest = null;
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++) {
    if (!o.hasOwnProperty(a[i][j])) {
      o[a[i][j]] = 1;
    } else {
      o[a[i][j]]++;
    }
    if (o[a[i][j]] > max) {
      max = o[a[i][j]];
      highest = a[i][j];
    }
  }
}
//this is the number with the highest occurence
console.log(highest);
```

Answer (score 0):

This ES6 solution iterates the sub arrays, and creates a map of the values, then in it moves the highest values to a map of the entire array. Afterwards, we map the Map entries (no pan intended) to new arrays that are filled with the numbers according to their highest count, and flatten the result.

```js
var data = [[2, 3, 5], [3, 3, 5], [2, 2, 3, 5]];

var result = [].concat(... // flatten the end result
  [... // convert the Map to entries array
    data.reduce((r, s) => { // reduce the array into a map of counts
      s.reduce((map, num) => map.set(num, (map.get(num) || 0) + 1), new Map) // get a Map of the current sub array counts
      .forEach((v, k) => r.set(k, Math.max(r.get(k) || 0, v))); // update the global Map if the sub array count of a number is higher
  return r;
}, new Map)]
  .map((s) => Array.from({ length: s[1] }, () => s[0]))); // map the entries into new sub arrays

console.log(result);
```